# Override multiple sqoop properties while executing sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh, sqoop2

I am finding that when overriding sqoop job properties at runtime, I am able to override only one property.

example 1: if i submit

```
sqoop job --exec test123 -- --query "select * from test where update_batch_id between 4 and 10 and \$CONDITIONS" -- --last-value 3
```

It overrides only query property

example 2: if i submit

```
sqoop job --exec test123 -- --last-value 3 -- --query "select * from test where update_batch_id between 4 and 10 and \$CONDITIONS"
```

It overrides only query property last-value property.

1. Is it possible to override multiple sqoop properties while executing a sqoop job? If not, is there a workaround available for this?
2. Can I update a Sqoop Job without running it?

Answer (score 1):

Use -- once to specify that you are overriding arguments like this:

```
sqoop job --exec test123 -- --query "select * from test" --last-value 3
```

Currently there is no way to edit a saved job from command line.